# AWK replace a column value when occurrences happen

Tags: batch-file, merge, awk

.
Hi everyone!

I need to replace some values in FILE2 file with the values on FILE1 file when date and time match.

**FILE1**

```
121216, 0100, 1.1,
121216, 0115, 1.0,
121216, 0130, 2.1,
121216, 0145, 1.8,
121216, 0200, 1.5,
121216, 0215, 1.3,
121216, 0230, 0.9,
121216, 0245, 1.2,
```

**FILE2**

```
121216, 0100, 2.3,
121216, 0200, ,
```

**OUTPUT**

```
121216, 0100, 1.1,
121216, 0200, 1.5,
```

Please an awk solution, speed is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
 awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}{$3=a[$1$2];}1' OFS=, file1 file2
```

Comment: This is a lot more fast than my bash script. Thanks for all!